# Union of multiple sp_MSforeachdb result sets

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I can successfully query the same table in multiple databases as follows:

```
DECLARE @command varchar(1000)
SELECT @command = 'select * from table'
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command
```

However, all of these results are, as expected, returned in different result windows. What's the easiest way to perform a union of all of these results?

Comment: `SELECT list, of, columns FROM database.schema.object UNION ALL SELECT list, of, columns FROM database2...`

Comment: The database names vary depending on which server I run this on, hence the use of sp_MSforeachdb.

Comment: `SELECT name FROM sys.databases` ;)

Comment: Create a temp table and then modify the @command to insert into the temp table.

Answer (score 8):

Please stop using `sp_MSforeachdb`. For anything. Seriously. It's undocumented, unsupported, and spectacularly broken:

- [Making a more reliable and flexible sp_MSforeachdb](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)
- [Execute a Command in the Context of Each Database in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5694/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server--part-2/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)

If you know that all databases have the same table (and that they all have the same structure!), you can do this:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = N'';

SELECT @sql = @sql + N'UNION ALL SELECT col1,col2 /*, etc. */
  FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.dbo.tablename'
FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id > 4 AND state = 0;

SET @sql = STUFF(@sql, 1, 10, '');

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

This ignores system databases and doesn't attempt to access any databases that are currently not `ONLINE`.

Now, you may want to filter this further, e.g. not include any databases that don't have a table called `tablename`. You'll need to nest dynamic SQL in this case, e.g.:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = N'DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cmd = N'''';';

SELECT @sql = @sql + N'

SELECT @cmd = @cmd + N''UNION ALL
SELECT col1,col2 /*, etc. */ FROM ' 
  + QUOTENAME(name) + '.dbo.tablename ''
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) 
 + '.sys.tables AS t
 INNER JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.sys.schemas AS s
 ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
 WHERE t.name = N''tablename''
 AND s.name = N''dbo'');'
FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id > 4 AND state = 0;

SET @sql = @sql + N';

SET @cmd = STUFF(@cmd, 1, 10, '''');

PRINT @cmd;
--EXEC sp_executesql @cmd;';

PRINT @sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

This doesn't validate the column structure is compatible, but you'll find that out pretty quickly.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to skin this cat is to use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max);

SELECT @sql = Coalesce(@sql + ' UNION ALL ', '') + 'SELECT list, of, columns FROM ' + QuoteName(name) + '.schema.table'
FROM   sys.databases
;

PRINT @sql
--EXEC (@sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

Had some collation issues and had to use

```sql
AND COLLATION_NAME = 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'
```